# I keep Getting Undefined

Tags: parsing, ionic2

[image]I'm Using ionic with parse and I'm trying to access the children from the `res.results`

> I still get the *undefined* error

```
 unfollow(){
      this.url ='https://meet-up-zionnite.c9users.io/app1/classes/friendslist';
     this.http.get(this.url, {headers : this.headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(res =>{
     this.localstorage.set('friendslist_db_detail',res);
     console.log(res.results.my_id);
     if(res.results == this.my_id){
     console.log('hey over here');
     }else{
     console.log("Not Match");
     }
     });
    }
```

> This is what I need to access:
>
> 1) ObjectId
>
> 2) my_id
>
> 3) f_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wow, i receive a help from one of my online tutor and it solved it
>   here is what have been missing

```
console.log(res.results[0]['my_id']);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved it :) please mark the answer as accepted so we can close the issue

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Glad to help :)